# Do technologies still get cheaper as they get older/discovered by others in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization 5, do technologies still get cheaper as they get older/discovered by others? Or is there no difference which order you research them in? In previous Civs, I believe they got cheaper as they got discovered by others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have met other civilizations that have discovered some technology you do not have, your cost to research that technology is discounted.

The [formulas](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=389702&page=5) are

```
discount = floor(30*civRatio)
civRatio = civs that are both met and have the tech / total civs on map
```

Here are the discounts for some civRatio values:

```
CivRatio : Discount
25%      :  7%
50%      : 15%
75%      : 22%
100%     : 30% (not attainable, as you would have the tech)
```

---

Given this information... one potential use is to push hard for civil service (food good for science), then catch up on other research.